# What to say when somebody isn't interested in our product?

Tags: phrase-request

Let's say you have a new product and want to send a free sample to a few influencers. How to respond (in a kind way) when somebody rejected you, especially when that person gave the reason why?

I'd like to say thank you for a response, but I also want to say that I understand, and I'm not offended that I was rejected. ( I don't know, something between "Sure thing," "Take care" and "Good luck!"- all of them combined into a few sentences). I'm looking for a "template" kind response in situations like that.

I'd be grateful if somebody came up with an idea how to express what I want to say.

Comment: or slightly more formal "No problem at all and thank you very much for your time."

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about writing.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to figure out what they are rejecting specifically about the product by asking probing, open and close questions. Then, suggest a suitable product that fits their liking.

Close the deal with the summary of benefits by re-emphasising the benefits that satisfy their personal concerns. If you don't want to give up yet.

End off with expressing appreciation for the interest in the products even though they didn't purchase anything. Ask them to come back again. Remember to give a sincere smile too!